# store fingeprint in SQLite using external fingerprint device in android

Tags: android

I want to store the Fingerprint of user in SQLite file in android Using external fingerprint device.I have a Finger print device of STARTEK FM220 model.
I already done the part of the name and email but in Fingerprint I totally stuck.

Comment: How is the fingerprint serialized? An image? A file? An array of bytes? I think you need to expound on what exactly you're trying to save.

Comment: An Image please help me.

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari how did you capture fingerprint from external device ?

Answer (score 1):

use a column of `BLOB` type as described in SQLite documentation

> BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html